# Fractional power of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I am given a matrix, for example $A = \begin{bmatrix}
       0.7 & 0.2 & 0.1           \\[0.3em]
       0.2 & 0.5           & 0.3 \\[0.3em]
       0           & 0 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}$,

how do I calculate the fractional matrix like $A^{\frac{1}{2}}, A^{\frac{3}{2}}$?

Comment: Why do you even think it is defined?

Comment: @GitGud Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @fgp Why would it be? Matrices necessarily having square roots? Square roots over what field? Furthermore the square root need not be unique, so using the symbol $\sqrt A$ leads to problems.

Comment: And for what's it's worth, this is a stochastic matrix, so non-real solutions are probably not acceptable.

Comment: I tried typing this into my graphing calculator and I am getting an error, so does this mean the answer is not unique?

Comment: @user121692 No, it means it doesn't make sense. You need to define the symbol $A^{1/2}$. If you're just looking for a matrix $X$ such that $X^2=A$, then you should specify so, but this isn't always possible.

Comment: @GitGud Well, you don't need a field to define *square roots* - for every ring $R$ there's the ring of polynomials $R[x]$ and you can thus ask for zeros of $s_a(x) = x^2 - a$ for any $a \in R$. Thus, $A^\frac{p}{q}$ is naturally interpreted as "find a matrix $B$ such that $A^p = B^q$". Whether or not there's a *unique* solution is a different question...

Comment: @fgp The field thing was just to set a background. And no, you cannot define a symbol as having more than one meaning in a fixed context.

Comment: @Git Gud  Well for my specific purposes, the matrix I am working with are Markov chains transition matrix and the matrix A I wrote above is the annual transition probability. I need to calculate semi-annual, I suppose what I am looking for then is as you said $X$ such that $X^2 = A?$

Comment: @user121692 OK, that has been answered. It's possible here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If a matrix is diagonalizable, then diagonalize it, $A=PDP^{-1}$ and apply the power to the diagonal

$$A^n=PD^n P^{-1}$$

The diagonal values are acted on individually.

---

octave gives:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}   0.85065 & -0.52573 &  0.57735\\
   0.52573 &  0.85065 &  0.57735\\
   0.00000 &  0.00000 &  0.57735\end{bmatrix}$$

$$D=\operatorname{diag}(0.82361, 0.37639,1)$$
I realize this is a numerical uglyness but I don't have a symbolic manipulation software at hand from this computer. However, the eigenvalues are different so this is a diagonalization.

The square root is
$$\sqrt{A}= \begin{bmatrix}0.82626 & 0.13149 & 0.04225\\
   0.13149 &  0.69477 &  0.17374\\
   0.00000 &  0.00000  & 1.00000\end{bmatrix}$$

---

This definition satisfies the requirement for roots that $(A^{1/p})^p=A$ for positive definite matrices (just like with $\sqrt{x}$ for scalars).

In a similar way, you can define functions on matrices through their power series. For instance, $e^A=P \exp(D)P^{-1}$ is perfectly well defined for diagonalizable matrices.

The convergence criteria and domain of these functions gets generalized and usually involves conditions for eigenvalues, positive-definiteness, symmetry, ortogonality and so on.

Note that the term *square root of a matrix* is sometimes used to represent a Cholesky decomposition, which instead works as $A=LL^T$ where $L$ is a lower triangular matrix. This is not the square root in the strictest sense, but it works like one for some numerical procedures.

Comment: Did you read the question?

Comment: Sure, the matrix is diagonalizable, use $n=\frac{1}{2}$ and calculate.

Comment: 'The'${{{{}}}}$?

Comment: If there are 8 "square roots", is only one of them a valid transition matrix?

Comment: @Neil the same applies as for reals: you define it to be the one with positive eigenvalues. That's why you start having problems selecting the branch when the original matrix is not positive definite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but $D^\frac{1}{2}$ still gives me an error?

Comment: What kind of an error? How are you calculating this?

Comment: So you are just square rooting each individual entry?

Comment: Exactly. A calculator probably doesn't allow this operation on a matrix, but serious software for matrix manipulation swallows this without a problem. For instance, in octave/matlab A^(1/2) works directly (and gives the same result). And yes, just take the square root of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this again.